# How to change Telegram supergroup title?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am using the Telethon library for python. How can I change Telegram supergroup name? Couldn't find this in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to edit the title of a supergroup you have to invoke the [`EditTitleRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/edit_title.html) method.

```
await client(functions.channels.EditTitleRequest(
    channel= YOUR_SUPERGROUP,
    title='‎‏‏‎͏NEW_TITLE'
))
```